# How to set ActionBar title from a getView method inside baseAdapter

Tags: java, android, methods, getview

I have a method as follows, would like to set an ActionBar title from this method so I can be able to access "position".

```
  @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View    songLay             = convertView;

        if (convertView == null) {
             songLay = songInf.inflate(R.layout.chat, parent, false);
            TextView body           = (TextView)    songLay.findViewById(R.id.msg_body);
            Sms currSong            = songs.get(position);
           body.setText(currSong.getMsg());
        }
        songLay.setTag(position);
        //new Chat().setTitle("lol");
        return songLay;
    }
```

**EDIT**

Inside the onCreate I have this:

```
Sms currMsg            = (Sms) msgList.get(1);
```

But where there's "1", should be the position found in the above method.

---

Can this be done here? If so how do I go about doing it? Or any alternatives?

Comment: What do you want? Why would you set the actionbar title in a *list*? The title would constantly be changing upon scrolling

Comment: why are u trying to do it from inside the getView method? doesn't make sense !!

Comment: @DavidMedenjak I want to access the "position", I don't know how to access it from the onCreate of AppCompatActivity. I want to change the title when each item is clicked on the list.

Comment: Do you have the adapter as a separate public class or as anonymous class?

Comment: you can set onItemClickListener on your `listView` in your activity then get position and what you want to do.

Comment: You should take a look at the [setOnItemClickListener(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)) method.

Comment: @user35603 yes the adapter is a separate class that extends baseAdapter.

Comment: @Titus will it return the "position" and where do I put the method? In the adapter on in the onCreate?

Comment: Yes, it will give you the position of the clicked item, you set this listener to the `ListView` and you can get the selected items from the adapter like this: `adapter.getItem(position)`.

Comment: @Titus let me try it, still starting with Java. If you can please make an answer with a proper example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
ListView lv = ...;
final MyAdapter adapter = ....;
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        ListItem item = adapter.getItem(position);
        MainActivity.this.setTitle(item.getName());
    }
});
```